# Cannot DIsplay a Snackbar Notice on Button Click - Notice is undefined

Tags: rest-api, notices

I am trying to use withSelect and withDispatch to display an admin notice when "save" button is clicked. I am using the following code from this [repo](https://gist.github.com/igorbenic/c0211d5382d1b62b97972713920b90e9#file-appnotices2-js) but it throws an error: "notices is undefined". Here is the code I am using:

```
import { Icon, Button, SnackbarList } from '@wordpress/components';
import { dispatch, withSelect, withDispatch } from '@wordpress/data';
import { compose } from '@wordpress/compose';
// Display and Dispatch the notice
const NewNotices = ({ notices, removeNotice }) => {
    
    //Uncaught TypeError: notices is undefined
    const snackbarNotices = notices.filter((notice) => notice.type === 'snackbar');

    return (
        <>
            <SnackbarList
                className="cwg-admin-notices"
                notices={snackbarNotices}
                onRemove={removeNotice}
            />
        </>
    );
}

export default compose([
    withSelect((select) => ({
        notices: select('core/notices').getNotices(),
    })),
    withDispatch((dispatch) => ({
        removeNotice: dispatch('core/notices').removeNotice,
    })),
])(NewNotices);
```

```
<>
//Create the notice on btn click
<Button
   isPrimary
   onClick={() =>
   {
   settings.save();
   dispatch('core/notices')
   .createNotice(
   'success',
   __('Settings Saved', 'slug'),
   {
   type: 'snackbar',
   isDismissible: true,
   icon: 
   <Icon icon="smiley" />
   }
   );
   }}
   >
   {__('Save', 'slug')}
</Button>
<NewNotices />
</>
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: It is the line where I am evaluating ```const snackbarNotices```. Apparently, ```notices``` param in the `<NewNotices/>` component is undefined (when i try to console.log it, it is undefined.)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The component was not rerendering, when clicking the "Save" button. I included the `compose` component in the render method and all is working good now:

```
const Notices = ({ notices, removeNotice }) => {

    const snackbarNotices = notices ? notices.filter((notice) => notice.type === 'snackbar') : [];
    return (
        <>
            <SnackbarList
                className="cwg-admin-notices"
                notices={snackbarNotices}
                onRemove={removeNotice}
            />
        </>
    );
}

const AppNotices = compose(
    withSelect((select) => ({
        notices: select('core/notices').getNotices(),
    })),
    withDispatch((dispatch) => ({
        removeNotice: dispatch('core/notices').removeNotice,
    })),
)(Notices);
```

--

```
<Button
   isPrimary
   onClick={() =>
       {
       settings.save();
       dispatch('core/notices')
       .createNotice(
           'success',
           __('Settings Saved', 'slug'),
           {
           type: 'snackbar',
           isDismissible: true,
           icon: <Icon icon="smiley" />
           }
       );
   }}
   >
   {__('Save', 'slug')}
</Button>
<AppNotices/>
```